# Unable to run script using webpack with npm or yarn - "Couldn't find the binary"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, scripting, package.json, yarnpkg

## Description

I'm trying to build my first React website using webpack. With gulp it builds fine. However when trying to build under administrator using webpack, when I run my script 'build' using the command 'yarn build', I get the following error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find the binary C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe;".
```

## Configuration

My node version is `v9.8.0`

My yarn version is `1.5.1`

My package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "mywebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My personal website.",
  "main": "./src/App.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
  "author": "Akli Aissat",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

My .babelrc:

```
{"presets": ["env", "react"]}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/App",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

I've also added Yarn to my environment variable Path.

## Error Logs

My yarn-error.log doesn't really give me any additional information about the error:

```
Trace: 
  Error: Couldn't find the binary C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
      at ProcessSpawnError.MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:186:110)
      at new ProcessSpawnError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:201:118)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:30237:18)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:207:12)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:379:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows 10. I'm wondering if this is a Windows issue as I encountered the same error when trying to open a directory in file explorer in my IDE (Atom). I checked my ComSpec value to make sure it's pointing to cmd.exe and it is ("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem was with my Windows configuration and not my project. I suspect the system environment variables was the specific issue. I resolved this by restoring Windows.